# signal x is array (1 to n) of type - VHDL

Tags: arrays, vhdl

I'm writing a code in VHDL language and there's something I want to implement:
 An array of FSM situations.

so I wrote as follows:
type C_state_type is (IDLE_C, X_chk_C, O_chk_C, tmp_draw_C);
signal cur_st_C, nxt_st_C is array (1 to n) of C_state_type;

any idea if this can be implemented somehow? If so, what should I
change? because modelsim doesn't agree to this.

Thanks, Amitai

Comment: Could you post the message from Modelsim?  And the code of your FSM where you're using the cur_st_C and next_st_C.

Answer (score 1):

define the array as TYPE too. then define the signals as your array. e.g.

```
type C_state_type is (IDLE_C, X_chk_C, O_chk_C, tmp_draw_C);
type C_state_array is array (1 to n) of C_state_type;
signal cur_st_C, nxt_st_C: C_state_array;
```

Comment: Explanation: when declaring a signal (or a constant, variable or port), you may only specify a type by its name or a create a subtype on-the-fly.

Comment: You can also create an unconstrained array type, like this : 'type C_state_array is array(natural range <>) of C_state_type;'.